# Batch add or subtract from variable

Tags: variables, batch-file

I have a batch file

```
@echo off  
set seconds=0  
:START  
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul  
echo %seconds%  
goto START
```

This basically says 0 then waits 1 second and then says 0 again...

I want it to add 1 to the variable `%seconds%` after each rotation like this:

```
@echo off  
set seconds=0  
:START  
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul  
echo %seconds%  
set seconds=%seconds%+1    
goto START
```

It doesn't work at all.
Is there a specific command that will increase the variable by 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set /a`. For example:

```
set /a SECONDS+=1
```

See `set /?` for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've been trying to do this for so long.
:-)
Thanks!